# CSV writing cannot be done

Tags: python, csv

CSV writing cannot be done.The list of "li_result" has data result and I want to write this data in csv file.
This is the code

```
fp = open('dataResult.csv', 'w')
w = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
csvwrite = unicode(li_result)

csvwrite_result = csvwrite.encode('sjis')

w.writerow(csvwrite_result)
```

But dataResult.csv is empty. Nothing error happen so I do not know what is wrong.
And I want to write the data in sjis code in csv file.(Now I use python2.7 so unicode is used to write letters,right?) I deleted these codes

```
csvwrite = unicode(li_result)

csvwrite_result = csvwrite.encode('sjis')
```

Still nothing is written.
What should I do to fix this?

Sample codes

```
fp = open(CSV_FILE_NAME_ACCOUNT, 'aw')
w = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
title = 'abc'
name = 'hoge'
time = '2010-04-20 0:0:0'

u_title = unicode(title)
u_name = unicode(name)
u_time = unicode(time)

s_title = u_title.encode('sjis')
s_name = u_name.encode('sjis')
s_time = u_time.encode('sjis')

list = [s_title, s_name, s_time]

w.writerow(list)
```

Comment: please post sample data and error message to investigate this further

Comment: thx ur comment.I do not have any error.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What operating system are you using? Is this your only code?

Comment: Please edit your question to include some sample data from `li_result` and show what you expect to see in `dataResult.csv`. That way we can run your script and reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

fp = open('system path to your file on which data to read', 'w')
w = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
title = 'abc'
name = 'hoge'
time = '2010-04-20 0:0:0'

list = [title, name, time]

w.writerow(list)
```